# Pig query giving error (positional parameter group by)

Tags: apache-pig

Will really appreciate if you can explain what i am doing wrong.

Script works for most part but when i use group by and dump results, i get error saying other_vertex_failure;

sample data

1,Apple,5.5
2,Orange,2.5
2,Orange,4.5
3,Kiwi,1.5
3,Kiwi,3.5
4,Banana,4.0
4,Banana,6.0

```
A = LOAD '/user/pig/apple.csv' USING PigStorage(','); **--this works**   
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 as ids:int, $1 as fruit:chararray,    
$2 as quan:int; **--this works**   
C = GROUP B BY ids; **--this works gives no error**
```

**but when i do dump C; it throws error.**

is that using names with positional parameters is bad idea in pig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign `alias` to your fields at `LOAD` itself.

Since you haven't done it, the fields default to type `bytearray`. And when it attempts to cast `bytearray` to `int`, it throws `ClassCastException`.

```
A = LOAD '/user/pig/apple.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (ids:int, fruit:chararray, quan:float);
C = GROUP A BY ids;
dump C;

(1,{(1,Apple,5.5)})
(2,{(2,Orange,4.5),(2,Orange,2.5)})
(3,{(3,Kiwi,3.5),(3,Kiwi,1.5)})
(4,{(4,Banana,6.0),(4,Banana,4.0)})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer franklinsijo. How would i handle data which has more than 200 columns and i am interested in only 3 of them?.  Using $ reference is only option in that case for group by? thank you.

Comment: I suggest you only assign the names without datatypes in the `foreach` to pick out only the 3 fields you are interested in. The exception arises here as you are trying to cast bytearray into an integer. Pig handles implicitly on casting the fields based on the operation you are performing.

Comment: Thank you so much, one last question if i need to assign them datatypes after foreach, what would be best way to do it?.

Comment: AFAIK you will run into issues if you try to cast `bytearray` to other datatypes. Either do explicitly on `LOAD` or do not do it at all. Let Pig handle it for you.